# Magento ver. 2.4.3 Error While Accessing Store Configuration

Tags: php, linux, magento, ssh, e-commerce

installed an extension using the composer, and then it didn't work, so what I did I just removed the extension, and then later on I wanted to do some configuration in the Magento 2 dashboard, then I figured out that the Store Configuration is not working, and it's showing the following error.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined index: id in /var/www/bmgpharmacy.com/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Structure/Element/Iterator.php on line 63

Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined index: id in /var/www/bmgpharmacy.com/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Structure/Element/Iterator.php on line 63
<pre>#1 Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Element\Iterator->setElements() called at [vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Structure.php:146]
#2 Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure->getTabs() called at [generated/code/Magento/Config/Model/Config/Structure/Interceptor.php:23]
#3 Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Interceptor->getTabs() called at [vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Structure.php:209]
#4 Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure->getFirstSection() called at [generated/code/Magento/Config/Model/Config/Structure/Interceptor.php:59]
#5 Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Interceptor->getFirstSection() called at [vendor/magento/module-config/Controller/Adminhtml/System/AbstractConfig.php:63]
#6 Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\AbstractConfig->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#7 Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Index\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#8 Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/weltpixel/m2-weltpixel-backend/Plugin/Utility.php:76]
#9 WeltPixel\Backend\Plugin\Utility->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#10 Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php:143]
#11 Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#12 Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#13 Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Config/Controller/Adminhtml/System/Config/Index/Interceptor.php:32]
#14 Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Index\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:245]
#15 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->getActionResponse() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:212]
#16 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:147]
#17 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#18 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#19 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#20 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:23]
#21 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:116]
#22 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:23]
#23 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:264]
#24 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub/index.php:29]
```

I tried to do the following steps and didn't help.

-Enabling Developer Mode
-Flushing the Cache
-Cleaning the Cache
-setup:upgrade
-setup:di:compile

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when you remove any extension that have config. To resolve this please check your `core_config_data` table in DB and remove those entry that is related to disabled/removed extension.

**Thanks**

Comment: There's no anything in the database related to the extension.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the code is OK, you can execute the following command to clear the Magento cache in Redis;

```
rm -rf generated/code/*  && rm -rf generated/metadata/* && rm -rf  pub/static/* &&  rm -rf var/cache/*  &&  rm -rf  var/composer_home/*  && rm -rf var/page_cache/*  && rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*  && php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:upgrade  && php -d memory_limit=-1   bin/magento setup:di:compile  && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US -f  && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy zh_Hans_CN -f   && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Caching can cause class-loading exceptions